# Delphi RAD Studio class completion issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I can't invoke class completion (via Ctrl + Shift + C) using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE6, if I have following class structure. Program works fine, but the IDE causes the following error. If I want to use it, I must comment `DescriptionArray`, which is somewhat annoying.

Therefore I would like to know, if anyone knows, where is the problem, or what I'm doing wrong.

```
GT_Class = class
type
  TCustomEnum = (ceValue1, ceValue2, ceValue3, ceValue4);
  TCustomSet = set of TCustomEnum;

const
  DescriptionArray : array[TCustomEnum] of string = ('Description1', 'Description2', 'Description3', 'Description4');
end;
```

Error Message

[image: Error message]

Comment: I think it is because there is nothing to complete in your class in the first place.

Comment: I can reproduce the error in XE6 but not in Berlin. Putting a visibility infront of the const though removed the error when invoking class completion.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you invoke class completion for this class?

Comment: This code snippet works just fine for me in Seattle. Looks like a bug in the IDE that has since been resolved.

Comment: @R. Beiboer No matter for which class in unit I use class completion or if there is something to complete, it always ends with this error.

Comment: @Stefan Glienke Thanks, that solved my problem. It's probably just as Johan said. Can you make it as answer?

Comment: Note that if you don't have any visibility directive, items are assumed to be published,(just like the components on a form are considered published) and what can be published is very limited.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The default visibility for classes inheriting from TObject is public and not published

Comment: @StefanGlienke: are you sure? I know that classes inherited from classes compiled with some option ($M?), IIRC starting at TPersistent have default published visibility.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: Found it: "If a member's declaration appears without its own visibility specifier, the member has the same visibility as the one that precedes it. Members at the beginning of a class declaration that do not have a specified visibility are by default published, provided the class is compiled in the {$M+} state or is derived from a class compiled in the {$M+} state; otherwise, such members are public". So indeed, if inherited from TObject, it is public. If inherited from TPersistent (which is compiled with $M+), it is published.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That is why you get `W1055` when adding a published property to a class derived from a class that does not have {M+}.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: OK, thanks. Never had that. I only use published for components or the like, so that problem never arose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by [Stefan Glienke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587106/stefan-glienke) in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347223/delphi-rad-studio-class-completion-issue#comment66025233_39347223). Actually it's a bug in Delphi XE6 and in other versions it has been resolved. You need to define visibility, `public` in this case, even if it shouldn't be needed.

```
GT_Class = class
public
  type
    TCustomEnum = (ceValue1, ceValue2, ceValue3, ceValue4);
    TCustomSet = set of TCustomEnum;

  const
    DescriptionArray : array[TCustomEnum] of string = ('Description1', 'Description2', 'Description3', 'Description4');
end;
```